# How to get another element instead of _id on elemMatch query on Mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a database set like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5aa7b4b31b93f3230857c303"),
    "pid" : "5aa7b3d0412f9625484514e3",
    "likes" : [ 
        {
            "userid" : "5a9e99b1c85c230edc207c01",
            "username" : "a"
        }, 
        {
            "userid" : "5a20ee35cdacc7086ce7742d",
            "username" : "g"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5aa7b4b31b93f3230857c304"),
    "pid" : "5aa7b3d0412f9625484514e4",
    "likes" : [ 
        {
            "userid" : "5a9e99b1c85c230edc207c01",
            "username" : "a"
        }
    ]
}
```

For checking on collection that My provided uid is exist or not I have a Query i.e

```
db.Collection.find({'pid': '5aa7b3d0412f9625484514e3'}, {likes: {$elemMatch: {'userid': '5a20ee35cdacc7086ce7742d' }}}, function(err, response){
console.log(response);
});

//it will return the result like this
{ _id: 5aa7b4b31b93f3230857c303, likes: [ [Object] ] }
```

Now I want pid with this data. _id is not matter for me.

Any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

try this, You need add pid in the second object if you don't want _id in the result, you can add `_id:0`

```
db.Collection.find({
    'pid': '5aa7b3d0412f9625484514e3'
}, {
    likes: {
        $elemMatch: {
            'userid': '5a20ee35cdacc7086ce7742d'
        }
    },
    pid: 1
}, function (err, response) {
    console.log(response);
});
```